# Why does this just make a blank output file

Tags: c++, fstream

I have this code that tries to write lines I receive from a pipe(fd_3) to an output file. The writer prints the lines that are received; and then then the lines are printed everything correctly, but the output file is blank every time. Any ideas?

```
close(fd_3[WRITE_END]); //wont be writing to Munch2

ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("output.txt");
if(!outFile) {
    printf("File output.txt could not be opened");  
}

while(read(fd_3[READ_END], (void*)line.c_str(), BUFFER_SIZE)) {
    printf("writer receives: %s\n", line.c_str());
    outFile << line;
}

outFile.close();

close(fd_3[READ_END]); //done reading
```

Comment: Reading into the data of a `std::string`? Bad idea. A `std::vector<char>` would be more suited for that.

Comment: I would advise you heed the 'c' in c_str() and NOT do what this is doing. use a std::vector<> instead. you may also find some useful information in the actual return value of that read() call. I would surmise it is a wee but different than BUFFER_SIZE.

Comment: This cannot be C code, so no need to tag it that way (well, it isn't really C++ code either, but that may be arguable ;))

Answer (score 4):

Probably because of that horrible

```
while(read(fd_3[READ_END], (void*)line.c_str(), BUFFER_SIZE)) {
```

Modifying c_str() isn't allowed, and there's a very extremely high almost perfectly certain chance that doing so will not only corrupt memory, but also NOT be reflected in the string content.

Comment: How do we even know he's getting *anything* off that read()? it isn't checked. And if he was I would surmise a seg-fault would be ensuing (if he's lucky). take the read() out of the equation due to failure and you have essentially an openfile/closefile. i.e. a blank file. He needs to fix both, methinks.

Comment: printf("writer receives: %s\n", line.c_str()); is printing the correct thing though, so i am assuming that it is reading correctly?

Comment: @Christian Stieber All i had to do was change coud << line to cout << line.c_str() and everything works fine.. just FYI

Answer (score 0):

problem might be lying here:

```
while(read(fd_3[READ_END], (void*)line.c_str(), BUFFER_SIZE)) {
```

c_str here says:

```
std::string::c_str<string>const char* c_str ( ) const;
```

Get C string equivalent
Generates a null-terminated sequence of characters (c-string) with the same content as the string object and returns it as a pointer to an array of characters.

so it returns const char * which means
a pointer to chars that you cannot change (you can change the pointer, so the malloc is ok, but you CANNOT change the characters pointed to, so the strcpy is bad).